# What is difference between Indy 9 and Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy

I am responsible for porting a Delphi 2007 application to C# and have absolutely no experience with Delphi. I am wondering what is the difference between the two Indy versions Delphi includes - Indy 9 and Indy 10. At this point I don't even know what an Indy is. Can someone help me out? Are they just different versions of the Delphi Library? What are the implications of using one or the other?

Thanks!

Comment: This is sort of off-topic, but your company is making two huge mistakes.  First, re-inventing working software is a very bad idea. ( http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html ) Second, if they absolutely must do it, they need someone who understands both Delphi and C# or the finished product is practically guaranteed to be a mess.

Comment: Well, I'm with you that someone familiar with both languages should be doing the conversion, but to your other point I disagree (for our specific problem) Yes the program works, but it needs updating from time to time, and our shop is moving away from Delphi altogether. There are less and less developers here who know Delphi, so to me it makes sense.

Comment: There is a .Net version of Indy 10. Your porting job might be a lot easier than you expect.

Comment: Well, that's another big mistake. Have you talked to other people who have ported stuff from Delphi to C#? The story usually goes like this: Since most of the Delphi people don't know C#, they can't help much with the porting, so you lose your domain-specific knowledge and experience. The new team has never worked on this before, so they make a bunch of mistakes that the Delphi team learned not to make the first time they did it.

Comment: The finished product runs a whole lot slower, takes up several times more RAM, has compatibility issues with the old version, and (since it's brand new code) is full of bugs. It ends up driving away at least 1/3 of your user base, straight into the arms of the competition. That's a very common story these days. A better bet would be to hire some more developers who know Delphi and maintain your existing codebase.

Comment: Look, this is an internal tool, and not all that complex - mainly copying files here and there. Although it might be nice to bring in a delphi/c# guru to convert all our internal applications, it's not going to happen. Thanks for the advice, but I think we are doing an OK job here!

Comment: Oh.  Well, if it's just an internal tool, go ahead and do whatever you want.

Comment: Jim Daniel (replying to your first comment): even then restarting clean in C# is IMHO usually better than conversion. If you really want to move away, do it wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indy is short for Internet Direct, an open-source library for doing networking. It's most commonly used for doing internet-related things, like sending emails and whatnot.

If you're porting from a legacy (say, Delphi 7) application that uses Indy 8 or 9, you'll find using Indy 9 in Delphi 2007 will be an easier port. ***If you don't care***, use Indy 10, as it's got many significant improvements to the library, and there are also some big architectural changes.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Indy 10 documentation, specifically the sections *What's new in Indy.Sockets version 10* and *Changes to the Object Hierarchy*

http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html

Answer (score 3):

Indy is a winsock wrapper that provides blocking socket behavior for network / internet programming (ftp, telnet, http, etc.)

Indy 10 is a newer version from Indy 9, and while the changes may improve the architecture, they removed some features and move things around.  If your program makes use of the parts that were moved or removed then porting to Indy 10 will be painful.

If you are moving from Delphi to C# then you will find the C# version of Indy is VERY different then the Delphi version.  Well at least when I looked at it.

Answer (score 3):

Some details:

- Indy10 is afaik already in D2005, though versions D2005 and D2006 allow to select which one to install.
- .... which doesn't matter, in any case always install the latest and greatest to get the newest fixes.
- Indy10 is better internally, but because they split it in several modules, beginners often have problems manually compiling it. Roughly the way of working of the Indy devels is thrust on the users, something that I think was unnecessary in retrospect since all packages must be updated as a whole in practice.
- Indy10 is portable. The indy9 Kylix support was not much more than an hack.
- Both work with FPC/Lazarus, but Indy9 only on win32. Indy10 also on Unix, OS X, win64 and wince. On lazarus, the Indy10 port is generally better.
- Last time I did significant work with it, the Indy10 examples were inferior to the indy9 ones.
- Indy10 got mired in the .NET morass, and is significantly less zero copy than indy9. This became worse over Indy10's lifetime.
- Some of the original goals of Indy10 (like fiber support for very high connection counts) were not realized. The need for fibers would need to be reevaluated anyway with the gigantic increase in (average) available memory though, and I also don't know how Microsoft sees fibers nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Indy Delphi is a library(Tcomponent) for Delphi representing the true power of WinSock.It provides components for tunelling,TCP/UDP connections and much more.

The official page is: http://www.indyproject.org
You will find everything you need there.

Indy 9 is an old version of Indy library.
Indy 10 came out in 2008 along with Delphi 2009.The whole structure of the library is changed in Indy 10.

In my opinion,Indy 9 was better.

Comment: Delphi 2006 ships with Indy 10.

Answer (score 1):

The [BorCon 2004 Programming Tracks](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/borcon2004/delphi) included an article by Chad Hower, [Upgrading to Indy 10](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32160).

> Abstract: This session covers the changes made to Indy 10 and how to
>   quickly port existing code. It also covers the advantages of Indy 10
>   and why you should port your code. While performance and other
>   demonstrations are shown, this session is a practical overview and
>   does not focus on demo code.

Content:

- Upgrading to Indy 10
- Indy 10 Status
- Installing Concurrent Versions
- Compatibility
- Migration
- Major Changes and Additions

Comment: +1 That's a good link to some good content. Much appreciated.